# How to upload a zip file and display it in PHP?

Tags: php

How can I upload a zip file, display the total size of the file, total number of files in the zip file, and display each file name in php code?

```
<?php
  if ($_FILES) {
      $fileName = $_FILES['zip']['tmp_name'];
        $zip   = zip_open($fileName);
          if ($zip) {
             while ($zip_entry= $zip_read($zip)) {
               echo "<p>";
               echo "<h3> Name:". zip_entry_name($zip_entry). "<h3>";
                  if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry)) {
                    echo "<h4>File Contents: </h4> ";
                     $contents = zip_entry_read($zip_entry);
                echo $contents;
                echo "<br /><br/>";
                zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
                  }
             }
              zip_close($zip);
           } 

  }
?>
<form method='post' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 <input type='file' name='zip'><br/>
 <input type='submit' name='upload' value='upload' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check file size and contain using verious inbuilt php methods . read from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_zip.asp)

Also can check below issue in your code

remove **$** from `while($zip_entry= $zip_read($zip)) {`

Answer (score 0):

Use [ZipArchive()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php)

```
    <?php
if ($_FILES) {
    $fileName = $_FILES['zip']['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_FILES['zip']['name'];
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if ($zip->open($fileName)) {
        echo "<h3> Name: " . $name . "<h3>";
        echo '<h4>File size: ' . filesize($fileName) . '</h4>';
        echo '<h4>Total files: ' . $zip->numFiles . '</h4>';
        echo "<h4>File Contents: </h4>";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
            $stat = $zip->statIndex($i);
            echo basename($stat['name']) . "<br>";
        }
        $zip->close();
    }

}

?>
```

Output

[image]